# Python build CFFI in API mode with Setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, packaging, python-cffi

I'm trying to learn about creating a `CFFI` modules, and packaging them with `setuptools`. When I run the build script `build_foo.py` I get an API mode library, but when I try to `pip install .` I get an ABI mode library.

Creates API mode

```
$> python build_foo.py
$> ls
build_foo.py  _one_cffi.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_one_cffi.c   _one_cffi.o
```

Creates ABI mode

```
$> pip install .
$> ls env/bin/site-packages
cffi                                           pkg_resources
cffi-1.11.5.dist-info                          pkg_resources-0.0.0.dist-info
_cffi_backend.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  __pycache__
easy_install.py                                pycparser
Foo-0.1.dist-info                              pycparser-2.19.dist-info
foopkg                                         setuptools
_one_cffi.abi3.so                              setuptools-40.6.2.dist-info
pip                                            wheel
pip-18.1.dist-info                             wheel-0.32.3.dist-info
```

---

### **Files**

build_foo.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cffi

ffi = cffi.FFI()
ffi.cdef("int get_one();")
ffi.set_source("_one_cffi",
"""
int get_one() {
    return 1;
}

"""
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ffi.compile(verbose=True)
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name = 'Foo',
    version = '0.1',
    packages = ['foopkg'],
    cffi_modules=["foopkg/build_foo.py:ffi"],
    install_requires = ['cffi']
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the filename ending with `abi3.so` has to do with Python's [PEP 425 abi tag](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/#abi-tag), not the ABI-mode option for how to use CFFI generated bindings. As far as I can tell the `cffi_module` install is simply failing to add any platform specific information to the shared object file, but I think that Python code that calls `foopkg` can still access `get_one()` in API-mode.